# MongoDB\Driver\Manager not working, ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, mongodb, apache

im trying to connect to mongodb using this code

`$client = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");`

However i keep getting this

**ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**

I dont know if this was because of my Apache Xampp or my MongoDb Driver

Here is the apache error log:

```
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:01.403066 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2224:tid 556] AH00428: Parent: child process 5920 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:01.604494 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2224:tid 556] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:01.635578 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2224:tid 556] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:01.635578 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2224:tid 556] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul  7 2016 11:13:22
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:01.635578 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2224:tid 556] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:01.638472 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2224:tid 556] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7632
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:02.108281 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7632:tid 608] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:02.239230 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7632:tid 608] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:02.271266 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7632:tid 608] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:03.374280 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2224:tid 556] AH00428: Parent: child process 7632 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:03.588130 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2224:tid 556] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:03.617244 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2224:tid 556] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:03.617244 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2224:tid 556] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul  7 2016 11:13:22
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:03.617244 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2224:tid 556] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:03.619840 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2224:tid 556] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7780
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:04.078121 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7780:tid 612] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:04.198572 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7780:tid 612] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Dec 06 00:36:04.227650 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7780:tid 612] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Please help me, i 've read through all similar problems but still confusing how to fix it

Comment: Could you share your `mongod` log too? Also can u establish a connection to it with mongo client? it seems its not fully working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are hitting the following bug: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPC-854 — we are actively looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I was using mongodb 1.2.1 x64 TS VC14
Problem was solved by switching to 1.1.10

I'll try to contact the maintainers.